# use document.body.style to @import js/css (JS/CSS help)

Tags: javascript, html, css, fonts

I don't know how to use `document.body.style` to use `@import` in JavaScript.

it should work like this in jsfiddle.com: "`document.body.style.import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&display=swap');`" but it highlights as "not good enough"

It's for a function listing it below

```
function font(fontData){
    var font = fontData.font;
  var applyFont = fontData.text;
  document.body.style.import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&display=swap');
  document.getElementById(applyFont).style.fontFamily = ;
}
```

I want to use it like this:

```
font({
   "font": "ubuntu",
   "text": "h1" // should apply to h1
})
```

Comment: Could you provide more information such as your usage case, would you be able to load that script as a stylesheet in your index.html file like this?

    `<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />`

Comment: yes i've updated now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's updated code that works

```
function addFont(font, fontName){
  const link = document.createElement("link")
  link.href = font;
  link.rel = "stylesheet"
  document.body.insertBefore(link, target);
  console.log(link)
  document.body.style.fontFamily = fontName;
}
addFont("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&display=swap", "'Roboto', sans-serif")
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).